# AWS SQS error retrieving messages in PHP with empty queue

Tags: php, amazon-sqs

I have code that is similar to various examples on SQS.

```
$sqs = \Aws\Sqs\SqsClient::factory(array(
    'key'=>'MYKEY',
    'secret'=>'MYSECRET',
    'region' => 'us-east-1'
));
$queueURL = 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/MYUSERID/MYQUEUENAME';


$messages = $sqs->receiveMessage(array('QueueUrl' => $queue));
print_r($messages);echo '<BR>';

foreach ($messages->getPath('Messages') as $message) {
    // Do something with the message
    echo $message;
}
```

However, I am getting an error in the foreach line: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.  The response to receiveMessage has no Messages, which makes sense because the queue is empty.  Here is what print_r($messages) displays:

```
Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model Object ( [structure:protected] => [data:protected] => Array ( [ResponseMetadata] => Array ( [RequestId] => 96a63acb-685c-5e42-a68b-76b7ea4ff16b ) ) )
```

In the `foreach` I have also tried `$messages['Messages']` and `$messages->get('Messages')`, all with no luck.

I am running this on a system that is outside of AWS but uses the key/secret for auth.

Thanks!

Comment: For now (at least) I have added `if (!isset($messages['Messages']))
    echo "No messages<BR>";
else ` in front of the foreach.

Comment: This was helpful to me.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/feature-models.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
if ($messages->getPath('Messages')) {
    foreach ($messages->getPath('Messages') as $message) {
        echo "Received: ".$message['Body'];
    }
}
```